# In Visual Studio is there a way to change the whitespace tab character?

Tags: visual-studio, whitespace

I prefer to code with white space visible and I use tabs. (no holy wars here please)

Is there a way to change the tab representation from an arrow to a bar or some other character?

I already have the color set on a dark gray color on a black background so it doesn't "intrude" when I'm not looking for them, but the default arrow representations are just not right.  Eclipse and many other editors use a bar or lines to represent tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even in the latest Visual Studio (and I have 2003, 2005, 2008 and 2010 installed), I didn't see any setting able to change the character used to display invisible characters like spaces (dots) or tabs (arrows).

So it doesn't seem possible.